# ¿Por qué el tamaño del registro no se incrementa si le agrego un método?

Tags: delphi

Tengo dos registros con los mismos campos, y uno de ellos tiene un conjunto de métodos. Siendo, de hecho, diferentes, ¿Por qué `SizeOf` devuelve el mismo valor para ambos?

```
{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

{$R *.res}

uses
  System.SysUtils;

type
  TData = record
    Age : Byte;
    Id  : Integer;
  end;

  TData2 = record
    Age : Byte;
    Id  : Integer;
    procedure foo1;
    procedure foo2;
    procedure foo3;
  end;

procedure TData2.foo1;
begin

end;

procedure TData2.foo2;
begin

end;

procedure TData2.foo3;
begin

end;

begin
  try
    Writeln('SizeOf(TData) = '+ IntToStr(SizeOf(TData)));
    Writeln('SizeOf(TData2) = '+ IntToStr(SizeOf(TData2)));
    Readln;
  except
    on E: Exception do
      Writeln(E.ClassName, ': ', E.Message);
  end;

end.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eso se debe a que el registro, en si mismo, solamente almacena los datos que lo componen, y no más información, como punteros a métodos (procedimientos o funciones). Los procedimientos y funciones son en si mismas un tipo de **dulce sintáctico** para evitar pasar el registro mismo como parámetro: la variable `self` que es agregada para ti *automágicamente* por el compilador.

Cada método que se declara en un registro tiene un parámetro extra para el registro mismo, por ejemplo:

```
  TData2 = record
    Age : Byte;
    Id  : Integer;
    procedure Foo1;
    procedure Foo2(SomeParam: Integer);
  end;
```

Es cambiado, tras bambalinas, a algo equivalente a:

```
  PData2 = ^TData2;

  TData2 = record
    Age : Byte;
    Id  : Integer;
  end;

  procedure TData2_Foo1(Self: PData2);
  procedure TData2_Foo2(Self: PData2; SomeParam: Integer);
```

De la misma manera, cada llamada que realizas también es *cambiada*, por ejemplo:

```
var
  Data: TData2;
begin
  Data.Foo1;
  Data.Foo2(1);
end;
```

Es cambiado por algo más o menos equivalente a:

```
var
  Data: TData2;
begin
  TData2_Foo1(@Data);
  TData2_Foo1(@Data, 1);
end;
```

Este parámetro *mágico* `self` es añadido al inicio o al final de la lista de parámetros, dependiendo de la convención de llamada en efecto, de acuerdo a la documentación: [Program Control (Delphi)](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE8/en/Program_Control#Handling_Method_Calls):

> - Bajo la convención *register*, `Self` se comporta como si hubiese sido declarado antes de todos los otros parámetros, por tanto siempre es pasado en el registro `EAX`.
> - Bajo la convención *pascal*, `Self` se comporta como si hubiese sido declarado después de todos los parámetros (incluyendo el parámetro por variable adicional que se pasa en ocasiones para almacenar el resultado de una función). Por tanto, es empujado al final, terminando en una dirección menor a todos los otros parámetros.
> - Bajo las convenciones *cdecl*, *stdcall*, y *safecall*, `Self` se comporta como si hubiese sido declarado antes de otros parámetros, pero después del parámetro adicional por variable (si existe) que es pasado para almacenar el resultado de la función. Por tanto, es el último a ser *empujado*, excepto por el parámetro por variable adicional.

Por supuesto que no hay una sintaxis real para esto, ya que es realizado *al vuelo* por el compilador, de tal manera que, por ejemplo, los nombres de los métodos no se cambian. Yo lo he expresado así tratando de escribir una respuesta fácil de entender.